# How to return all documents from a dynamic array of Object Id's?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my Node get route, I am trying to return all documents that belong to each Object Id in a dynamic array.  The array is dynamic because it changes depending on what 'company' is being queried from the Mongo database.

I have tried about a hundred different things from many different Stack Overflow answers and none seem to answer my current problem unfortunately.

My current route currently returns an array of only one document, from one id, and it's the closest I've gotten so far.  Here it is:

```
 router.get('/:category/:company', (req, res, next) => {

  Company.findOne({ "companyName": req.params.company}, (err, company) => {

    console.log("printing all reviews", company.reviews);

    if(!company) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: "Can't find the company you're looking for at the moment." });
    } else {

          Review.find({'_id': { $in: company.reviews } },
             (err, reviews) => {
             console.log("getting all reviews for company", reviews);

             res.json({
               message: "Retrieving your company",
               company: company,
               reviews: reviews
             });

        });



    }

  });
```

});

Note:  company.reviews does show the full array of reviews that belong to the queried company, but the mongoose method is only returning an array with one of those id's.

I have not been able to find any mongoose or mongodb methods that return the full array.  Any help much appreciated.

The returned document as shown in the console:

[image]

Showing the full array of reviews:
[image]

Comment: Can we get an example doc (or two)?

Comment: The [Documentation on find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) does not show quotation marks around the field being queried.

Comment: @JeffMatthews Thanks for the reply.  I have tried it with and without quotes, however it returns the same result.

Comment: @PeteGarafano Thanks for the reply.  I've added an image above of the document as shown in the console.

Comment: You said the console.log shows all the reviews' company Id's.  Are you sure they are all of the type ObjectId and not string?

Comment: Your screen shot does not show the contents of the reviews array for the given company.

Comment: @JeffMatthews . Whoops, just added them.  They are showing as id's, not _id's, however I have tried querying 'id' and it returns the same result.  Edit: 
 They *are* showing as strings.

Comment: What does console.log(typeof company.reviews[3]) show you?

Comment: @JeffMatthews It returns 'object'

Comment: Now, go to your Reviews collection and see if you can see a document with an _id which matches that same value.  Is it there?

Comment: @JeffMatthews Yeah, my collections shows all the reviews that have been made, and it includes the one review that's returned from the find() in my route.

Comment: @JeffMatthews Edit:  The one review it returns is always the last review from the full array, if that means anything.

Comment: @JeffMatthews I just dropped my entire reviews collection, and now when I add new reviews the method works and is retrieving all of them for each company.  I don't know why that worked, but it did.  Do you know why that might have done the trick?

Comment: Maybe the index was corrupted and it needed to rebuild the index.  Glad you got it working.  Just out of curiosity, it is working with quotes around the '_id'?

Comment: @JeffMatthews Hmm interesting, ok.  Thanks a lot for your help.  Yeah I currently have quotes around the _id and it is working.